# ggplot2 geom_bar, ticks and limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following function:

```
miss.case = function(x){
  y = apply(x, 1, is.na)
  y = apply(y, 2, sum)
  return(y)
}
miss.hist = function(df, percent=T) {
  m = miss.case(df)
  d = data.frame(number.of.NA = m)
  max.miss = max(m)
  min.miss = min(m)

  if (percent) {
    d$percent = (d$number.of.NA/sum(d$number.of.NA))*100
    g = ggplot(data = d, aes(x = number.of.NA)) +
      geom_bar(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))*100)) + 
      scale_y_continuous('percent') +
      xlab("Number of NAs") +
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=min.miss:max.miss)
    return(g)
  }
  else {
    g = ggplot(data = d, aes(x = number.of.NA)) +
      geom_histogram() +
      xlab("Number of NAs") +
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=min.miss:max.miss)
    return(g)
  }
}
```

Which makes a nice histogram of missing data by case with ggplot2. Almost. To see, try with some test data:

```
#make some test data
test.data = as.data.frame(iris)
set.seed(1)
which.remove = cbind(sample(1:150, 250, T),
                     sample(1:5, 250, T))
for (row in 1:nrow(which.remove)) {
  test.data[which.remove[row,1],which.remove[row,2]] = NA
}

#plot missing
miss.hist(test.data)
```

Which should give you this:

[image]

You see what is wrong. The right part of the plot is weirdly empty. Now you may think, this is easy to solve with setting the limits, i.e.: `limits=c(min.miss, max.miss)`. But no, this fixes the problem, but removes the ticks!

[image]

Changing the order of them does not make a difference. How do I fix both problems?

Comment: I just ran the whole script and got the following error. `Error in miss.hist(test.data) : could not find function "miss.case"`. I wonder if you want to double check your code.

Comment: Sorry, its a custom function from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deleetdk/psych2/master/psych2.R I will update post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a discrete scale with an `integer` vector. Transform it to a `factor` instead

```
g = ggplot(data = d, aes(x = factor(number.of.NA,levels=as.character(seq(0,max.miss,1))))) +
```

Comment: This works, yes. Is there some actual reason why using integers does not work?

Comment: I am not sure about this. `ggplot` is very sensible to data types, so I would guess it expects a continuous scale whenever the data is numeric/integer. That is what your second plot suggested.

Comment: One thing about using `as.factor` is that it removes empty bars, whereas with integers they would be present. This means that one has to pay more attention to the labels under the bars, since they may be e.g. 0, 1, 12, 54. With integers they would have been 1, 2, 3, ..., 54.

Comment: @Deleet good point. To avoid this, we could force the levels : `factor(number.of.NA, levels=as.character(seq(0,max(number.of.NA))))`